# Voltage drop to water heater

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, water-heater

A couple months ago, I replaced my water heater.  For the sake of full discolsure, I replaced an AO Smith 40 gal lowboy with a Bradford-White 50 gal lowboy, but the electrical requirements were still completely the same: 240v, 25A, two non-simultaneous 4500w elements.

Since the installation almost three months ago, I have had two instances where I experienced a loss of hot water. Both instances were several weeks apart, and well over a month after the install, the second instance happening just a bit ago.  Diagnosing the issue both times, there was low voltage at the wire nuts between the heater and the line coming in from the breaker box: around 92v. Simply flipping the breaker to OFF then back to ON corrected the issue.  The breaker did not APPEAR (or feel) tripped, but looks can be decieving.  FWIW, the breaker box is a GE.

Since I'm experencing an occasional low voltage issue, I am leaning towards an issue with the breaker itself, for which simply replacing the 25A double pole breaker would be my remedy.  But could there be a different issue I should look into before replacing the breaker?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
As per request, I took off the breaker panel cover, only to find a new monkey wrench to throw into our conversation.  Here is the breaker, which the more and more looking into this, and as cheap as breakers are, I might a step ahead and (at worst) out less than $10 if I replace the breaker.  The arrows indicate the one in question:
[image: 25Amp 2 pole circuit breaker, wires spliced]

I am sure you quickly noticed the spliced wiring that is present which some genius wrapped up with electrical tape.  Turns out these spliced wires lead to an older style load control bypass:

[image: Load Control Bypass Only]

Red wire #1, which is spliced in with the black line in the box does tie in with the black wire with the LCB box.  The black line in image 1 goes out to the water heater. The other red line stays red until it gets to the LCB and then you can see it goes across the jumper bar to the white which then proceeds out to the water heater.

This may be an opportunity to clean up a pretty ugly mess, but now I am wondering if my issue is Duke Energy playing around with me by shutting down my water heater and not turning it back on.

**FINAL UPDATE:**
I replaced the breaker, and took the opportunity to remove the wires going to the Load Control box, which from all apearances is no longer being used.  I was relieved to find that the splices underneath were done with crimped splice caps, and then covered with the electrical tape.

Everything checks out good with votage at the heater and back in the panel box now.

I appreciate everyone who commented and served as a sounding board so I could confirm what I was orginally suspecting!

Comment: Check the breaker itself, check all the connections to the breaker, any junctions between the breaker and the WH, and the WH connections themselves.

Comment: What’s the voltage across the output screws at the breaker?  Also, I suspect a measurement problem, because if the problem is really a 148V voltage drop, something would be *rather hot*...   Also, are any other appliances acting weird?

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica I had confirmed the voltage by removing the wire nuts and putting the probes directly to the wires.  Yeah, don't shoot me.   As soon as I reset the breaker to off then on, the voitage returned to 240 (I did hook everything back up prior to that).  No other issues, but the water heater is on its own circuit.

I will add that when I went back near my box to get tools for another project (and after my original post) I noticed that old familiar electrical hum/buzz (albiet very faint) that went away after pushing on the breaker itself.

Comment: When you removed the wire nuts, were the wires still twisted together and the WH still connected, or were the wires loose and the WH disconnected?

Comment: @brhans Wires were still twisted.  I applied multimeter probes directly to the wires coming from the breaker, however.

Comment: Measuring off de-nutted wires is legit if you're careful. However I would be keen to see the voltage across the 2 screws on the double pole breaker.  If that is good, then it must be in the wiring.  Otherwise I still doubt it's the breaker, and suspect something much more serious, the next place I'd check is the main lugs or any other 2-pole breaker.   If you shut off all your 2-pole or tied breakers, does half the house lose power?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the breaker itself?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Getting ready to upload the pics now & edit my original post.  Have a nice monkeywrench to throw at things, too.

Comment: Yikes! I sure hope the electric company didn't make that splice in your box!

Comment: @FreeMan Yeah.  My thought upon seeing that was somewhere along the lines of "well that's a mell of a hess!" except a bit more colorful with four-lettered things I can't say on a forum like this.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica You suggested there could be a more serious issue.  Could that old Load Control box be along those lines?  I am wondering if the best thing to do would be to connect the line straight back into the breaker and have nothing going to the old load control? 

BTW,  this is the only breaker I've had issue with at all. Everything else has good voltage and has never been suspect or tripped without reason.

Comment: You mentioned a hum , buzzing , I would check the buss for damage , turn the breaker off and rock it out and look for pitting on the contact point of the buss and the breaker, a loose breaker can burn through the buss or the snap  On contacts for the breaker. , this is not common with GE that I have seen but it happens.

Comment: I didn't know about the load control box at the time I saw it. My line of thinking was a "lost hot" from the pole.  When the WH thermostat called for heat, it would effectively be in series with the 120V loads on the dead pole, which would bring them back to life and also heat the water slowly.  However in light of the load controller, I now favor your "Edison is turning off your water heater power as part of load-shed" theory.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica That's okay.  I thought the load control was tied to my HVAC not the water heater, at least at one time.  There is a functioning control box next to my HVAC unit on the exterior of the house, and I had (incorrectly) assumed this was an older one tied to that somehow.

Comment: Also are you using the correct type of breaker for this panel?  I don't like precautionary "why not?" breaker replacement because that's a risk area for fitting the wrong make of breaker in the panel, which can create its own problems down the road.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Most definitely.  Its a GE split-bus box (makes sense as the house is vintage 1974), so the dual THQL1125 (old) is going to be replaced with a THQL2125.  That could certainly be an easy mistake to make if one were to go down to that big blue (or orange) store and just buy a circuit breaker, so thank you for checking on that!

Comment: @EricShock -- can you measure 240V across the breaker screws at least?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Once I removed the panel for the earlier edits I did that, indeed.  I was able to verify 240v. But the problem has not repeated itself since.  I will be replacing the breaker today and will give a final update.

I'm seriously considering removing the spliced wires going to the Load Control box.  It seems to be superflous at best, and if the power company still has control over it,  to me the safety of electrical taped splices isn't worth the couple pennies they gift me each month.

Comment: I am just going to say, "WOW!" on the splice.  I am glad you were able to properly fix it.

Comment: @EricShock -- post your last update as an answer and I'll give you a +1 for it :)

Answer (score 1):

FINAL UPDATE: I replaced the breaker, and took the opportunity to remove the wires going to the Load Control box, which from all apearances is no longer being used. I was relieved to find that the splices underneath were done with crimped splice caps, and then covered with the electrical tape.

Everything checks out good with votage at the heater and back in the panel box now.

I appreciate everyone who commented and served as a sounding board so I could confirm what I was orginally suspecting!